# Trying to share core data entity between apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

I want to create a entity in app A and save it into the app group shared space and access that entity in app B.  This is my current approach, i'm not a master of core data so i'm sure i'm doing something wrong, the following code is for creating the entity in app A and saving it to the shared area.  I receive no errors and the entity is created successfully

```
NSError * error = nil;

NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"DataModel" withExtension:@"momd"];
NSManagedObjectModel *mom = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:mom];
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
[moc setPersistentStoreCoordinator:psc];

NSURL *storeURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"GROUP_IDENT"];
storeURL = [storeURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"sharedDB.sqlite"];
NSPersistentStore *store;

store = [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error];

Report *report = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Report" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
report.categoryID = @"THIS IS A TEST";

if ([moc save:&error] == NO) {
    NSAssert(NO, @"Error saving context: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
}
```

And then trying to access this data in the other app as follows

```
NSError * error = nil;

NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"DataModel" withExtension:@"momd"];
NSManagedObjectModel *mom = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
NSAssert(mom != nil, @"Error initializing Managed Object Model");

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:mom];
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
[moc setPersistentStoreCoordinator:psc];

NSURL *storeURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"GROUP_IDENT"];
storeURL = [storeURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"sharedDB.sqlite"];


NSError *error = nil;
NSPersistentStore *store = [psc persistentStoreForURL:storeURL];



NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Report"];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Report" inManagedObjectContext:moc]];
[request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
NSArray * fetchedObjects = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

store is always nil!  If anyone has some suggestions or help that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You should use shared bundle:

```
NSBundle *sharedBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"com.company.sharedName"];
```

Instead of this:

```
[NSBundle mainBundle]
```

Comment: The data model for the ManagedObjectModel is in the main bundle though..